# VSCode launch.json's attribute 'skipFiles' doesn't skip files

Tags: vscode-debugger

No matter what configuration of skipFiles I try, I still get pulled into an abyass of internal code preventing any form of productive debugging. I use Vue 3 and Vite.

Here is the config

```
            {
                "type": "chrome",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Launch Vue App (Vite)",
                "url": "http://localhost:3000",
                "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
                "sourceMaps": true,
                "skipFiles": [
                    "<node_internals>/**",
                    "<node_internals>/**/*.js",
                    "<node_internals>/**/*.ts",
                    "${workspaceFolder}/<node_internals>/**",
                    "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**",
                    "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**",
                    "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
                    "${workspaceFolder}/lib/**/*.js",
                    "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.ts",
                    "runtime-core.esm-bundler.js"
                ]
        }
```

As you can see I have tried all possible combinations, including manually writing runtime-core.esm-bundler.js yet I still get there when I try to debug a simple const foo = ref(0).